# A small detail about regular functions on affine irreducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field, $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$ an affine irreducible variety, and $ U \subseteq X $ an open subset. Suppose that there are $f,g,f',g' \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $fg'=gf'$ over $U$ as polynomial functions on $X$. We know that $U$ is dense in $X$ by irreducibility. Now, I think that I'm forgetting something very trivial, but I can´t seem to understand the following statement: **Since $U$ is dense over $X$, it follows that $fg'=gf'$ over X**. Why is that so? This kind of argument reminds me of what happens when we have two continuous functions $h,w: Z\longrightarrow Y$ into a Hausdorff space $Y$. But I suppose this isn´t the case,  since the Zarisky topology isn´t even Hausdorff...our open sets are just "too big".

I'm actually reading Andrea Gathmann's notes in Algebraic Geometry as an introduction to the definition and characterization of regular functions over an affine variety (the notation used is quite similar to the one I'm using). The argument in bold is essential if one wants to look at "quotients" in the field $K(X)$ of rational functions of $X$ as mappings $\phi: X \longrightarrow K $ that are locally described as ACTUAL rational functions. We identify elements of the coordinate ring $A(X)$ as actual polynomial functions on $X$, but we can´t identify elements of its field of fractions with actual rational functions on $X$ in general. We only codify that $f/g = f'/g'$ in $K(X)$ iff $fg'= gf'$ as polynomial functions on $X$.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Well, the vanishing set of fg'-gf' is a closed set of X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $fg'-gf'$ is zero on $U$.  Moreover, since $0$ is closed, it's preimage is a closed set in $X$.  Therefore, the set of points where $fg'=gf'$ is a closed set containing $U$.  Hence it is all of $X$.